# Hyperreal star mapping isomophism

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

I've been reading through Goldblatt's book on the Hyperreals. And the star mapping is defined to be:

*r=[**r**]=[(r,r,r,...)]. Where r is a real number, and [**r**] denotes the equivalence class of the constant sequence r. It then goes on to say that the map r--> *r is an order preserving isomorphism from the Reals to the Hyperreals.

Question: How would one go about showing this though?

Comment: Have you already shown that the hyperreals are totally ordered?

Comment: $a<b$ implies $[(a,a,\dots)]<[(b,b,\dots)]$ by the definition of $<$ for the hyperreals.